# What open source project management systems accept a Teamwork.com data-export importation?

Tags: project-management

I have some old data in Teamwork.com that I'd like to preserve for history / posterity, but haven't been able to find any options for importation of the exported database into another open source / free service. Any options I may be missing in this regard?

Comment: Lol. Love the strange and wrong classifications that constantly happen like the "closing" of this question.